# Upload file django admin

Tags: python, django, admin

I'm creating a admin form where users can upload files. I want this to be stored in a secure place where the public can't get it. I'm using a standard form with a `FileField` and no model. Is there a way I can store the files in a folder within the app folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do that by specifying the path in your settings.py file eg.  `MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'`

Comment: Doesn't this then mean that the files that are being uploaded are accessible  for the public? Which I don't want

Comment: No, it doesn't because the files will be located in the path you specified in your app folder.

Comment: In my opinion the accessibility of the files is more an issue of the configuration of you webserver and the server hosting your site.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this
**Add these line in your project level file urls.py(which is auto generated when project is created)**

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = urlpatterns + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**And add these lines in your settings.py**

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```